# How to catch indicator click event to show modal Tradingview?

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, nuxt.js, tradingview-api

how can i catch the click event on self generated indicator? I want when I click on my indicators, it will show the modal in the tradingview library

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUAtE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bFoF.png)